# How to add nodes of different shapes in react-cytoscape?

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am trying to have different nodes of different shapes based on the `classes` attribute

This is the elements:

```js
const elements = [
    { data: { id: "p1", label: "Node 1", classes: "place" } },
    { data: { id: "t1", label: "Transition", classes: "transitions" } },
    { data: { id: "t2", label: "Transition2", classes: "transitions" } },
    { data: { id: "p2", label: "Place 2", classes: "place" } },
    { data: { id: "p3", label: "Place 3", classes: "place" } },
    { data: { source: "p1", target: "t1" } },
    { data: { source: "t1", target: "p2" } },
    { data: { source: "t1", target: "p3" } },
    { data: { source: "p2", target: "t2" } },
    { data: { source: "p3", target: "t2" } },
  ];
```

and this is my styles:

```js
const cyStyle = [
    {
      selector: ".place", 
      style: {
        "background-color": "blue",
        shape: "ellipse",
      },
    },
    {
      selector: ".transitions",
      style: {
        "background-color": "red",
        shape: "rectangle",
      },
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      style: {
        width: 3,
        "line-color": "#ccc",
        "target-arrow-color": "#ccc",
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
        "curve-style": "bezier",
      },
    },
  ];
```

The styles to the edges are applied, and if I add a `selector: "nodes"` it gets reflected on the nodes, however I want the two different classes of nodes that I have to appear in different shapes.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You should write `classes` outside the `data` object.
```

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  layout: {name: 'grid', rows: 2},
  style: [{
      selector: '.shape1',
      css: {
        'shape': 'ellipse'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: '.shape2',
      css: {
        'shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }    
  ],
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'        
        },
        classes: 'shape1'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        },
        classes: 'shape1'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        },
        classes: 'shape2'
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        },
        classes: 'shape2'
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0n1',
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1',
          weight: 3
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1n2',        
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n2',
          weight: 5
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2n3',        
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n3',
          weight: 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#button {
  z-index = 1000;
}

#cy {
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50;
  z-index = 900;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.10.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```